# Netlogo: How to count turtles between specified coordinates in a row?

Tags: count, coordinates, netlogo

How to count turtles between specified coordinates in a row?
For example, we want to count turtles that are between (min-pxcor 0) and (max-pxcor 0).
The following is sample syntax, but does not work:

`count turtles with [(min-pxcor 0) < (max-pxcor 0)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are looking for turtles with `pycor = 0` and `pxcor` between a min and max value, say `minpx` and `maxpx`, you would write

```
count turtles with [pycor = 0 and pxcor >= minpx and pxcor <= maxpx]
```

Note that `min-pxcor` and `max-pxcor` are NetLogo reporters giving the edges of the world in the x dimension, so all turtles will have `xcor`s between those two values.  If that is what you want, you don't have to test their `xcor`s at all.

Comment: Thanks for your sample code and good ideas! Actually the parts, which are "maxpx" and "minpx" do not work, so I fixed them likes followings and it worked.
count turtles with [pycor = 0 and pxcor> = min-pxcor and pxcor <= max-pxcor]

Comment: Sorry, I might have been clearer.  `maxpx` and `minpx` were numbers that you would supply to limit the row to a subset of the possible x values, e.g., from pxcor = -3 to pxcor = +6..  Since `min-pxcor` and `max-pxcor` are the minimum and maximum x coordinates that a patch can have and thus that a turtle could be on, it is redundant to check whether a turtle is between them.  All turtles must be.  You could simply say `count turtles with [pycor = 0]` and get the same answer.